# Why Javascript converts numbers in strings to numbers?

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner to coding. I was learning javascript and came across a problem which I couldn't figure out. Hope someone could explain this to me (much appreciated).

The function isNaN is supposed to check whether a variable let's say is not a number. The problem is when you code like this,

```
 var b = "44" //this is  a string
 if ( isNaN(b) ) {
 alert("b is not a number");  // does not give me the alert
 }
 //But if you put an else statement to this
 else {
 alert("b is a number"); //alerts as b is a number when it's a string
 }
```

I would really appreciate if someone could explain why this particular piece of code alerts as "b is a number" when it's a string. Many thanks.

Comment: `isNaN` isn't for checking whether the type of a value is or isn't a number, it's for checking whether the value is specifically [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN). Also there's type coercion involved.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Confusing_special-case_behavior

Comment: The idea is that `isNaN` essentially checks if `Number(x)` will (won't) return a useful result. To check for a string, use `typeof x == "string"`.

Comment: Also, from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN): "When the argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number.". You can also check Number.isNaN for reference

Comment: This explains everything https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `isNaN` is called "is Not a Number", it does not check whether a value is "not a number". It specifically checks if a value is [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

`NaN` is a special value. According to MDN: "It is the returned value when Math functions fail (Math.sqrt(-1)) or when a function trying to parse a number fails (parseInt("blabla")).

Because B is not `NaN`, the else clause will fire and "B is a number" will be alerted.

**Checking for numbers**

If you want to know whether a value is a number, you can use `typeof`:

```
var b = "44";
if (typeof b !== "number") {
  alert("b is not a number");
} else {
  alert("b is a number");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: A followup to the question I asked, so from what i understood "NaN" is the value you get when a math function fail (MSDN). So if that's the case, the alert should trigger now but it doesn't. Why?


  var a = 4;
  var b = "fd";

  var c = a*b;
   alert(c);

   if isNaN(c) {
 alert("it's not a number");
    }

Comment: Because you forgot parentheses in the `if` statement. It should be `if( isNaN(c) )`

Comment: Thank you, it turned out to be a dumb question (silly me).

Answer (score 2):

`Global.isNaN` converts the argument to a number, then checks wether it is `NaN`. You are probably looking for [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) which checks wether it is not of type number or NaN.

Polyfills:

```
 Global.isNaN = n => +n !== +n;
 Number.isNaN = n => typeof n !== "number" ||  n !== n;
```

They will behave the same for `NaN`, numbers, strings and objects, and will behave different for Booleans and strings representing numbers (the global one returns `false`, the number one `true`).

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the correct explanations given about isNan with a solution to your problem:

Instead of using `isNan()` to identify a number, you could just use `typeof` which will help you identify the type of the variable:

```
var b = "44" //this is  a string
  if ( typeof b === "number" ) {
    alert("b is a number");  // does not give me the alert
  }
  //But if you put an else statement to this
  else {
    alert("b is NOT a number"); //alerts as b is a number when it's a string
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> The `isNaN()` function determines whether a value is `NaN` or not. Note: coercion inside the `isNaN` function has interesting rules; you may alternatively want to use `Number.isNaN()`, as defined in ECMAScript 2015.
>
> ...
>
> Since the very earliest versions of the `isNaN` function specification, its behavior for non-numeric arguments has been confusing. **When the argument to the `isNaN` function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is `NaN`**. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to numeric type result in a valid non-NaN numeric value (notably the empty string and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric values zero or one), the "false" returned value may be unexpected; the empty string, for example, is surely "not a number." The confusion stems from the fact that the term, "not a number", has a specific meaning for numbers represented as IEEE-754 floating-point values. **The function should be interpreted as answering the question, "is this value, when coerced to a numeric value, an IEEE-754 'Not A Number' value?**"
>
> The latest version of ECMAScript (ES2015) contains the [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) function. `Number.isNaN(x)` will be a reliable way to test whether `x` is `NaN` or not. Even with `Number.isNaN`, however, the meaning of `NaN` remains the precise numeric meaning, and not simply, "not a number". Alternatively, in absense of `Number.isNaN`, the expression `(x != x)` is a more reliable way to test whether variable `x` is `NaN` or not, as the result is not subject to the false positives that make `isNaN` unreliable.

Source: [`isNaN` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

From the Specification:

**18.2.3 `isNaN(number)`**

> The `isNaN` function is the `%isNaN%` intrinsic object. When the `isNaN` function is called with one argument `number`, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let `num` be `ToNumber(number)`.
> 2. `ReturnIfAbrupt(num)`.
> 3. If `num` is `NaN`, return `true`.
> 4. Otherwise, return `false`.

Source: [ECMA-262 6th Edition - 18.2.3 `isNaN(number)`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isnan-number)